# Error running phpunit test using Phing

Tags: jenkins, phpunit, phing

Jenkins version - 2.22

Phing version - 0.13.3

PHPUnit version - 5.7.19

**phpunit.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="bootstrap/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">./app/Managers</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

**build.xml**

```
...
<coverage-setup database="./report/coverage/database">
    <fileset id="coverageFileSet" dir="./app/Managers">
        <include name="**/*Manager*.php" />
    </fileset>
</coverage-setup>
<phpunit pharlocation="./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit" configuration="./phpunit.xml" printsummary="true" haltonerror="true" haltonfailure="true" codecoverage="true">
    <formatter type="clover" outfile="report/coverage/clover.xml"/>
</phpunit>
<coverage-report outfile="report/coverage/coverage.xml">
    <report todir="report/coverage"/>
</coverage-report>
...
```

When I run the `phing` target in `Jenkins`, I get following error.
`unrecognized option -- b`

What am I doing wrong? or any help how to debug this issue ?

Note - This is `laravel-5.4` application and when I run `phpunit` from application's root folder its working.

Comment: The message `unrecognized option -- b` [obviously originates from PHPUnit](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/src/Util/Getopt.php#L84). Maybe the Phing task uses it the wrong way?

Comment: @Joe yes, but I wonder If I'm doing it wrong? Any way I can find what is that option `b`, it may helpful to find the issue

Comment: Sounds pretty much like this [Issue](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/1967). According to the [commit mentioned there](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/commit/e814242fe377747490ccc31e455765b7abd3d5ff) it might work with an older version of PHPUnit (< 4.8).

Comment: Running `phing -verbose` or even `phing -debug` might reveal the options `phing` actually uses to start `phpunit`. Maybe you'll find your `b` there.

Answer (score 0):

You said you are using Phing version - 0.13.3, which is not very plausible. You should try using **Phing 3.0.0-alpha3**, it has a lot of improvements.

Also, I think the following answer can help you: [Phing and PHPUnit, just cant get even the most basic thing running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42907053/phing-and-phpunit-just-cant-get-even-the-most-basic-thing-running/48674840#48674840)