# Phing and PHPUnit, just cant get even the most basic thing running

Tags: phpunit, phing

### Using a composer-installed bin

I'm running a most basic task as follows:

```
<autoloader autoloaderpath="vendor/autoload.php">

<target name="asdf">
        <echo msg="test"/>
        <phpunit configuration="app/phpunit.xml"
                 haltonerror="true"
                 haltonfailure="true"
                 pharlocation="bin/phpunit"
        />
</target>
```

Now simply running this task:

```
phing -debug asdf
```

Will result in:

```
  +Task: echo
    -calling setter EchoTask::setMsg()
     [echo] qwerqwer
  +Task: phpunit
    -calling setter PHPUnitTask::setConfiguration()
    -calling setter PHPUnitTask::setHaltonerror()
    -calling setter PHPUnitTask::setHaltonfailure()
    -calling setter PHPUnitTask::setPharLocation()
#!/usr/bin/env php
Cannot open file "asdf.php".
```

### Using a .phar

Using the same  configuration except pharlocation:

```
  +Task: echo
    -calling setter EchoTask::setMsg()
     [echo] test
  +Task: phpunit
    -calling setter PHPUnitTask::setConfiguration()
    -calling setter PHPUnitTask::setHaltonerror()
    -calling setter PHPUnitTask::setHaltonfailure()

BUILD FINISHED
```

No errors, but the phpunit tasktype doesnt start.

### Unrecognized option

Had a third simple variant that seemed fine, which resulted in 'phpunit: unrecognized option -- p' that i sadly cant reproduce..

#### Versions

- PU 5.7
- Phing 2.16
- PHP 7.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you used PHPUnit 5.7. Did you use namespaces in your tests?

The current version of Phing is not compatible with namespaces like `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase`, you have to use the old class `\PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` instead.

The next Phing's release is going to be compatible with PHPUnit's namespaces (https://github.com/phingofficial/phing/issues/659). Meanwhile you can create `phpunit.xml` and add this to `build.xml` to run your tests:

```
<target name="phpunit" description="Run tests">
    <exec executable="bin/phpunit" passthru="true">
        <arg value="--configuration"/>
        <arg value="app/phpunit.xml"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue when invoking Phing using Jenkins. The Phing plugin for Jenkins adds a *-buildfile* switch to the command calling Phing and when I removed this switch (running the command manually), my PHPUnit test suit was executed successfully. I recommend avoiding the Phing plugin for Jenkins and using a shell execution step to invoke Phing directly:

```
/path/to/php /path/to/phing/binary/
```